# Add embedded ruby helper with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add or append a ruby helper that iterates in an active record response??

I have tried this (with .html or .append):

```
$( ".result" ).html('<%= @products.each do |product| %><label>product</label><% end %>');
```

But the problem is that it return all the list of products like this:

```
productproduct[#<Product id: 35, name: "", price: nil, category: "", quantity: nil, qty_unit: "", company_id: 108, created_at: "2014-11-13 17:22:33", updated_at: "2014-11-13 17:22:33", cost: nil, seller_bonification: nil>, #<Product id: 36, name: "Salmon", price: 3000, category: "Pescado", quantity: 1, qty_unit: "kg", company_id: 105, created_at: "2014-11-13 17:25:27", updated_at: "2014-11-13 17:25:27", cost: nil, seller_bonification: nil>]
```

So, I get only the string "product" from product and not the iterated object itself, I cant access to each product. And after that, I get all the list of products in a Active Records way.
I've also tried this without the "=", like this:

```
$( ".result" ).html('<% @products.each do |product| %><label>product</label><% end %>');
```

And I only get:

```
productproduct
```

I dont know how to solve this issue. Maybe, a better practice is to use gon gem, or turbolinks, or a hash?? Does anyone knows??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
$( ".result" ).html('<% @products.each do |product| %><label><%= product.name %?</label><% end %>');
```

if you want to print something from product ( e.g. name in my code sample).

So remove = for @product.each tag;

add <%= %> to the product and call whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

When using `each`, don't use `<%=` but `<%`

`<%=` tries to put return value of `each`. Even `each` has return value in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

In **erb template**  for print something `<%= %>` is used and while looping or condition check you have to use `<% #condition %>`